# why cant I use log files in java runtime

Tags: java, runtime, exec, runtime.exec

I have (in java),

```
rt.exec("qq.exe -i ..(some other parameters) > qq.log");//*1
```

when I run qq.exe -i ..(some other parameters) > qq.log in terminal It works fine and keeps the qq.log file correctly.

However using rt.exec (*1) doesnt work. " > qq.log" part causes problem. When I delete that part rt.exec (*1) works but I cant have qq.log file this time.

What causes this problem and Is there any soln??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rt.exec()` can't execute sh/bat code. It's just invoking another program. When you try to redirect the output stream of qq.exe with the `>` symbol, which is specific to shell, java doesn't understand what to do.

An alternative is when you execute some program with the `exec` method, get the [`Process`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) returned by `rt.exec()`.
A [`Process`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) can give you an OutputStream to the application, an InputStream from the application and even an ErrorStream for a started application.

With the InputStream, you can programmatically read the result of qq.exe and all you have to do is to write this into a file.

Comment: thnx a lot. Minor correction: it is not OutputStream, it is InputStream.  Outputs of programs go into InputStream. OutputStream is our outputs going into the program...

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 added ProcesBuilder.Redirect class that allows to redirect input/output/error streams to/from files. It can be used like this:

```
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cat", "/proc/meminfo");
    // Append all errors from process to log file:
    builder.redirectError(Redirect.appendTo(new File("/tmp/my.log")));
    Process process = builder.start();
```

Using corresponding methods you can redirect input and output. The full example is here: [Run external process in Java 7](http://farenda.com/java/java-external-process/).